# How to use both isalpha( ) and isdigit( ) to filter out what isn't a letter or digit?

Tags: python, string, loops, palindrome

I need to filter out everything that is not a letter or digit using  `.isalpha()` and `.isdigit()`.
Currently I'm using definition and `.replace()`.

```py
exit = False
takeout = ":.;!@#$%^&*()}{|\+=" + " "
while exit == False:
    data = input(("Enter set OR press E/e to exit: "))
    data = data.lower()
    for i in takeout:
        data = data.replace(i,"")
        newdata = data[::-1]
        print("input printed backwards is: ", newdata,"\n")
    if len(data) <= 1:
       data = input("enter set which numerical/alphabetical values are equal or greater than 2 or enter E/e to exit:")
    elif (data == data[::-1]):
        print(data, " is a palindrome\n.")
    else:
        print(data, "is not a palindrome\n.")
    if data == "E" or data == "e":
       exit = True
```

Comment: is it necessary to use those two functions?

Comment: Can you post your code? And BTW there is one function isalnum

Comment: @KarinaK Yes I was told to use both isalpha() and is digit().

Comment: exit = False 
takeout =":.;!@#$%^&*()}{|\+=" + " "
while exit == False:
 data = input(("Enter set OR press E/e to exit: "))
 data = data.lower()

 for i in takeout :
  data = data.replace(i,"")

 newdata = data[::-1]
 print("input printed backwards is: ", newdata,"\n")
 
 if len(data) <= 1:
   data = input("enter set which numerical/alphabetical values are equal or greater than 2 or enter E/e to exit:") 

 elif(data == data[::-1]):
       print(data, " is a palindrome\n.")
 else:
       print(data, "is not a palindrome\n.")

 if data == "E" or data == "e":
    exit = True

Answer (score 1):

```py
def remove_special_chars(string):
    output = []
    for c in string:
        if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit():
            output.append(c)
    return ''.join(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieved that in the following way:

```
from sets import Set

allowed_chars = Set('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
validationString = 'inv@lid'

if Set(validationString).issubset(allowed_chars):
    return validationString # nothing to remove from this string
else:
    return ''.join(i for i in validationString if Set(i).issubset(allowed_chars))
```

Comment: Instead of manually entering all the letters and numbers, just use `string.ascii_letters` and `string.digits`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression split and filter and isdigit and isalpha

```
 sentence ="1 I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have found them all to be of good quality. huh? The product looks more like a stew than a processed meat and it smells better-looks better. My Labrador is finicky-pampered and she appreciates this product better than most."
 sentence=sentence.lower()
 words=re.split("[, |-|\?|\!|\.]",sentence)
 words=filter(lambda w: ((w.isdigit() or w.isalpha()) and len(w)>0),words)
 print(*words)
```

output:

```
  1 i have bought several of the vitality canned dog food products and have found them all to be of good quality huh the product looks more like a stew than a processed meat and it smells better my labrador is and she appreciates this product better than most
```